# Removing FilePath from QStringList

Tags: qt, qstring

I have a `QStringList` full of file path. But these file path isn't in normal format, i have environment variable in the file path, for example `%PATH_OF_VAR%/GEN/abc.txt`. I am using `fileName` but apparently it doesn't work. What I want to do is, I need to get only fileName out of this and save it in another `QStringList`. When any fileName is deleted from 2nd `QStringList` respective filepath needs to be automatically deleted from he 1st `QStringList`

EDIT:

```
Xmlget.load(String);
QStringList list;
QStringList preset_scr;
QString name;

xmlget.findAndDescend("INIT_SKRIPTE");
while(xmlget.findNext("SKRIPT"))
{
    preset_scr.append(xmlget.getString());
}
for(int i=0;i<preset_scr.count();i++)
{
    QFile file(preset_scr.at(i));
    name = file.fileName();
    list.append(name);
}
qDebug()<<list;
```

EDIT2: I got trimming working by using `QFileInfo`  instead of `QFile`, i have no clue how to update 1st `QStringList` when there is some changes in 2nd `QStringList`

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

If your file path always look like `%PATH_OF_VAR%/GEN/abc.txt` then you can fill second list like this:

```
foreach(const QString& path, preset_scr) {
    QString name = preset_scr.at(i).split("/").last();
    list.append(name); 
}
```

Second. When you remove string from second list, you can remove path from first list like this (assuming `fileName` is the name to be removed):

```
for(int i = preset_scr.count() - 1; i>=0; --i) {
    if(preset_scr.at(i).split("/").last() == fileName)
        preset_scr.removeAt(i);
}
```

Comment: fileName is removed by me, i want filepath to be removed automatically

Comment: You can't do this automatically. Just call this piece of code evety time when you removing data from second list.

Answer (score 0):

You could try iterate over list and split every string to get only filename:

```
QStringList preset_scr;
QStringList newList;
QString filename;

for( const auto & s : preset_scr ) {
    filename = s.split("/").last();
    newList.append(filename);
}
```

Comment: I got it split, i am stuck at updating my 1st qstringlist(which is filepath) whenever my 2nd QStringlistis edited